# Dynamically size an Android tablelayout?

Tags: android, resize, textview, tablelayout

I have a `TableLayout` that I create dynamically which simply contains a bunch of `TextViews`. The problem is that the table has 11 columns which usually causes some of the `TextViews` to extend off the side of the screen (especially in portrait mode).

Is there anyway to dynamically adjust the size of the view in the `TextViews` until they all fit on screen? Is there anyway to check if a specific `TextViews` is currently visible on the screen? Can anyone think of a decent way to ensure that all the columns get displayed?

What is the best way to handle `tablelayouts` with a lot of columns?

Answer (score 0):

You may try bounding the size of the View when adding them into `TableRow`.

```
TableLayout tableLayout;
TableRow tableRow;
TextView textView1;
TextView textView2;
...
tableRow.addView(textView1, width, height); // width can be screen width divided by 11
tableRow.addView(textView2, width, height);
...
tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a single row that is a LinearLayout and add Weighted controls to this layout. The only problem is if you do not insert the same number of controls (columns) for each row, then they will not line up.